# Typescript Generic Types cannot assign arbitrary properites

Tags: reactjs, generics, typescript

Shouldn't a Generic Type allow the same thing as a JavaScript type of Any?  Typescript is teaching me that Generic Types don't include Any type ability.

In this code, Typescript tells me is doesn't like current.url, current.name...

```
private OnRenderCell<T>(item,index ){
                 var current = item as  T;
                 return <Button data={current.url} 
                    className="action-button"
                    width="150"
                    onClick={this.ProjectClicked.bind(this)}>{current.name}
                 </Button>
}
```

I know, code doesn't make sense, but it was just the first step in a refactor effort to get to generic. I want any generic T of Item to be passed in, but haven't figured out how to peel off properties.  Perhaps a callback?  If that's true, then that's all I need, just callback to get values.

Comment: generic is not any. generic programming means the algorithm can happen for multiple types that respect  the same set of restrictions. you can read more about it on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming

Comment: For what you're doing you don't need to use generics. Just give the `item` param a type including `url` and `name` (maybe define an interface for this).  You'll then be be able to pass into the function any object that has those fields.